# Why is Command not invoked when binding value is null?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command, winrt-xaml

I have made a grid that I would like to initiate with null or empty values.
But when my textblocks binded value is null the click/tap won't trigger the command.
When I have a value it works fine.
I've also tried to use `string.empty` and " " which won't work either. Would be happy if somebody could shed some light on this.

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="GridPuzzleOuter">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Puzzle.Rows}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="270">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cells[0].CellValue, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                    <core:InvokeCommandAction
                                        Command="{Binding CellTappedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Cells[0]}"/>
                                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cells[1].CellValue, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                    <core:InvokeCommandAction
                                        Command="{Binding CellTappedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Cells[1]}"/>
                                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Rows class

```
public class Row : ObservableObject
{
    public Cell[] Cells { get; set; }
    private RelayCommand<Cell> _cellTappedCommand;

    public RelayCommand<Cell> CellTappedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _cellTappedCommand ?? (_cellTappedCommand = new RelayCommand<Cell>((param) => Cellclick(param)));
        }
    }

    private void Cellclick(Cell param)
    {
        var vm = (new ViewModelLocator()).Main;
        vm.SelectedCell = param;
        // Do stuff...
   }
}
```

Edit:
Solved by changing XAML into:

```
<Border Grid.Column="0">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction
                    Command="{Binding CellTappedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Cells[0]}"/>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cells[0].CellValue, Mode=TwoWay}">
    </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

Comment: I think you need [TargetNullValue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066931/how-does-wpf-handle-binding-to-the-property-of-a-null-object)

Comment: I think I solved this one by myself, I simply moved out the command from the textblock and to the Border instead.

JAT, thanks for your input, I didn't know about TargetNullValue (or  FallbackValue), so I learnt something new today!

Answer (score 0):

Just move your interaction code to the surrounding `Border` and be sure to set the `Background` property to `Transparent`. Problem solved.

// Best of luck!