# What if parent object in property path is null?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

How do we control what happens if one of the parent objects in the property path is null? For example:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ActiveDrawing.PrintCommand}" />
```

What if `ActiveDrawing` is null? I want this button to be disabled in that case, but WPF keeps it enabled. I have tried setting `FallBackValue` to null, like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ActiveDrawing.PrintCommand, FallbackValue={x:Null}}" />
```

but it doesn't make a difference. The button keeps enabled.

N.B. Setting `TargetNullValue` to `{x:Null}` also doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Implement a PrintCommand ,and in CanExecute, check the ActiveDrawing.PrintCommand. Remove the direct coupling.

Comment: I do have `PrintCommand` and `CanExecute` implemented. Problem is that WPF won't go that far to evaluate `CanExecute` if `ActiveDrawing` is null. If you're asking me to move ALL my commands from ActiveDrawing to the current context, that is too big an undertaking. I believe there should be an easy way of specifying a value in case binding evaluation fails for some reason.

Comment: In fact I hoped `FallbackValue` is solely for this purpose, but somehow it is not working as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have devised the following workaround for now.

1. Create a new class named `NullCommand`:

   ```
   Public Class NullCommand
     Implements ICommand

     Public Event CanExecuteChanged As EventHandler Implements ICommand.CanExecuteChanged

     Public Sub Execute(parameter As Object) Implements ICommand.Execute
     End Sub

     Public Function CanExecute(parameter As Object) As Boolean Implements ICommand.CanExecute
       Return False
     End Function
   End Class
   ```
2. Create an instance of the class in the Resources section:

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
     <vm:NullCommand x:Key="NullCommand" />
   </RibbonGroup.Resources>
   ```
3. Use this object as your FallbackValue:

   ```
   <Button Command="{Binding ActiveDrawing.PrintCommand, FallbackValue={StaticResource NullCommand}" />
   ```

Hurrah! It works. Whenever the binding property path fails for any reason, your button will be disabled.

TBH, I don't like this solution for one sole reason. `FallbackValue` should have handled this situation.